# Check if a package exist in Ant script?

Tags: ant

I am writing Ant script to generate Javadoc for my program. the ant script as:

```
<javadoc access="public" 
    source="1.6" 
    sourcepath="${basedir}/../${current.project}/src" 
    destdir="${basedir}/dist/doc/${current.project}" 
    packagenames="${current.project}" />
```

But I got trouble if the `${current.project} (packagenames="${current.project}")` does not exist, then Ant will throw error and stop the progress.

I want to ask is there any way to check that if the package name (`${current.project}`) does not exist, then Ant will continue to do its jobs until end?

Answer (score 0):

you could add the attribute `failonerror="false"` to your javadoc task, so it will prevend the whole build from failing - but the javadoc task won´t run anyway.

Comment: But that is not what I want. My need is to want to keep javadoc task running even if some packages do not exist.

Comment: Is it possible for you to work with wildcards in a default value for  ${current.project} - like com.yourcompany.project.* ?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. But does it mean that by placing com.yourcompany.project.*, it means generate javadoc for package starting with "com.yourcompany.project". If so, this is not what I am trying to do as I just want to generate for the package "com.yourcompany.project" only.